# как столбец из xlsx превратить в данные, записанные через запятую, в txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, csv, обработка-данных

У меня есть файл xlsx, в котором один столбец с номерами. нужно его преобразовать и записать в txt как строку, где данные будут разделены запятой. как лучше это сделать с помощью python?

Answer (score 2):

Воспользовавшись уже знакомым для вас Pandas:

Исходный Excel:

```
In [95]: pd.read_excel(r'D:\temp\.data\a.xlsx')
Out[95]:
      a     b     c
0     1     2     3
1    11    22    33
2   111   222   333
3  1111  2222  3333
```

Предположим, что нас интересует первая колонка (`a`):

```
In [96]: pd.read_excel(r'D:\temp\.data\a.xlsx', usecols=[0]).T.to_csv(r'd:/temp/out.csv', header=None, index=False)
```

out.csv:

```
1,11,111,1111
```

Пошагово:

```
In [97]: pd.read_excel(r'D:\temp\.data\a.xlsx', usecols=[0])
Out[97]:
      a
0     1
1    11
2   111
3  1111

In [98]: pd.read_excel(r'D:\temp\.data\a.xlsx', usecols=[0]).T
Out[98]:
   0   1    2     3
a  1  11  111  1111
```

Comment: `pandas` замечательно подходит для подобных манипуляций с данными.

Answer (score 1):

Для чтения Excel 2010 `.xlsx` файлов (ECMA 476/ISO 29500) можно использовать [`openpyxl` модуль (чистый Питон)](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import openpyxl # $ pip install openpyxl

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=r'D:\книга.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook['Лист1']
column = worksheet['F']
with open('книга_Лист1_F.txt', 'w') as file:
    print(*[cell.value for cell in column], sep=',', file=file)
```

Или более компактно:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import openpyxl # $ pip install openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=r'D:\книга.xlsx')
with open('книга_Лист1_F.txt', 'w') as file:
    print(*[cell.value for cell in wb['Лист1']['F']], sep=',', file=file)
```

Чтобы в общем случае поддерживать ячейки, которые могут запятую содержать (для чисел необязательно), можно использовать [csv модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv
import openpyxl # $ pip install openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='книга.xlsx')
with open('книга_Лист1_F.txt', 'w', newline='') as file:
    csv.writer(file).writerow([cell.value for cell in wb['Лист1']['F']])
```